# SQL - Select non duplicates column values

Tags: sql, unique-values

I have the following SQL table containing a group ID, and the users that needs access to the groups. I have 3 types of users, but if it is the same user in all 3 types, then I only need to select 1 and not all 3.

This is my table:

[image: This is my table:]

And this is the result I would like from the select

[image: Result]

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Can you provide your query code?

Comment: Also: you need distinct values always, or only when the count is three? (eg. if the count is 2, you display that 1 or 2 times?)

Comment: Distinct values always

Comment: I don't have any code yet because I do not know how to solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 3 selects with union:

```
select group_id,
       csp
  from your_table
union
select group_id,
       ep
  from your_table
union
select group_id,
       em
  from your_table
order by 1, 2;
```

Union will eliminate the duplicates.